# Keep p-value format from the `emmeans::joint_tests()` output in a knitted pdf

Tags: r, kable, kableextra, emmeans

This question might be related to [knitr's kable is printing 2.29e-30 as "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514017/knitrs-kable-is-printing-2-29e-30-as-0/45531529)

I am knitting my `.Rmd` to .pdf.
I'd like to print p.values as are from `emmeans::joint_tests` below, i.e. `< 0.0001`.

```
library(emmeans); library(kableExtra)

data("trees")

model <- lm( Volume ~ Girth*Height, data=trees ) 

joint_tests(model)


model term   df1 df2 F.ratio p.value

 Girth          1  27 438.245 <.0001 
 Height         1  27  36.959 <.0001 
 Girth:Height   1  27  30.512 <.0001
```

But if I wrap `kable` around my table, the original format disappears. How do I tell `kable` to keep the original format from the `joint_tests` output?

```
kable(joint_tests(model))
model  term          df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
1      Girth           1    27  438.245 0.0e+00
3      Height          1    27  36.959  1.7e-06
2      Girth:Height    1    27  30.512  7.5e-06
```

Per @rawr suggestion, the code below solved the format issue but added a line to the table

```
kable(read.table(text = paste(gsub('model', '', capture.output(joint_tests(model))), collapse = '\n')))

V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
term    df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
Girth   1   27  438.245 <.0001
Height  1   27  36.959  <.0001
Girth:Height    1   27  30.512  <.0001
```

Comment: these answers dont make sense to me, it sounds like you want the `<0.001` not more digits. the model is being printed with `emmeans:::print.summary_emm` which formats the pvalues but returns the original object. what about `kable(read.table(text = paste(gsub('model', '', capture.output(joint_tests(model))), collapse = '\n')))`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, your code solved my `p.value` format problem but it added a line to the top of the table (V1 V2 V3 V4 V5).

Comment: add `header = TRUE` to `read.table`

Comment: There is an `xtable` method that may help

Comment: I'll look at this and see if there's a reasonable option in the `print.summary_emm` method for exporting the formatted table. I obviously put some attention to formatting the results reasonably, and I hate looking at P values in exponential formats.

Comment: Thank you very much. `xtable` does help but I got a latex chunk of text in the middle of a .pdf file. It's OK since I can upload the .tex file to Overleaf and have it corrected there but it would be great to not have to do that.

Comment: Hmmm, I think there are different output formats available with xtable, e.g. html, but maybe that doesn' help.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest brute-force solution,

```r
kable(joint_tests(model), digits = Inf)
```

although it prints *too many* digits  ...

Comment: Thank you. I didn't mean to ask kable to print too many digits, just the number of digits that `joint_tests` gives me, which in this case is "<0.0001".

Answer (score 1):

OK. I just added an `export` argument to the `print` method for `emmGrid` objects. It returns a `list` with a `summary` and and `annotations` element. Example:

```
> noise.lm = lm(noise/10 ~ size * type * side, data = auto.noise)
> EMM = emmeans(noise.lm, ~ size * side | type)
> xprt = print(pairs(EMM), export = TRUE)

> xprt
$summary
$summary$`type = Std`
 contrast    estimate   SE      df   t.ratio   p.value  
 "S L - M L" "  -1.500" "0.312" "24" " -4.811" "0.0009 "
 "S L - L L" "   7.167" "0.312" "24" " 22.984" "<.0001 "
 "S L - S R" "   1.833" "0.312" "24" "  5.880" "0.0001 "
 "S L - M R" "  -0.667" "0.312" "24" " -2.138" "0.3023 "
 "S L - L R" "   4.833" "0.312" "24" " 15.501" "<.0001 "
 "M L - L L" "   8.667" "0.312" "24" " 27.795" "<.0001 "
 "M L - S R" "   3.333" "0.312" "24" " 10.690" "<.0001 "
 "M L - M R" "   0.833" "0.312" "24" "  2.673" "0.1182 "
 "M L - L R" "   6.333" "0.312" "24" " 20.312" "<.0001 "
 "L L - S R" "  -5.333" "0.312" "24" "-17.105" "<.0001 "
 "L L - M R" "  -7.833" "0.312" "24" "-25.123" "<.0001 "
 "L L - L R" "  -2.333" "0.312" "24" " -7.483" "<.0001 "
 "S R - M R" "  -2.500" "0.312" "24" " -8.018" "<.0001 "
 "S R - L R" "   3.000" "0.312" "24" "  9.621" "<.0001 "
 "M R - L R" "   5.500" "0.312" "24" " 17.639" "<.0001 "

$summary$`type = Octel`
 contrast    estimate   SE      df   t.ratio   p.value  
 "S L - M L" "   0.333" "0.312" "24" "  1.069" "0.8887 "
 "S L - L L" "   6.000" "0.312" "24" " 19.243" "<.0001 "
 "S L - S R" "   0.500" "0.312" "24" "  1.604" "0.6042 "
 "S L - M R" "   0.333" "0.312" "24" "  1.069" "0.8887 "
 "S L - L R" "   5.000" "0.312" "24" " 16.036" "<.0001 "
 "M L - L L" "   5.667" "0.312" "24" " 18.174" "<.0001 "
 "M L - S R" "   0.167" "0.312" "24" "  0.535" "0.9941 "
 "M L - M R" "   0.000" "0.312" "24" "  0.000" "1.0000 "
 "M L - L R" "   4.667" "0.312" "24" " 14.967" "<.0001 "
 "L L - S R" "  -5.500" "0.312" "24" "-17.639" "<.0001 "
 "L L - M R" "  -5.667" "0.312" "24" "-18.174" "<.0001 "
 "L L - L R" "  -1.000" "0.312" "24" " -3.207" "0.0389 "
 "S R - M R" "  -0.167" "0.312" "24" " -0.535" "0.9941 "
 "S R - L R" "   4.500" "0.312" "24" " 14.432" "<.0001 "
 "M R - L R" "   4.667" "0.312" "24" " 14.967" "<.0001 "

$annotations
[1] "P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 6 estimates"
```

You have to manually export each part of `xprt$summary`, e.g. via `knitr::kable(xprt$summary[[1]])` or `lapply(xprt$summary, knitr::kable)`

This will get pushed to GitHub soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It doesn't work for me yet. Rmarkdown doesn't knit. I have tried `knitr::kable(xprt$summary[[1]])` or `kableExtra::kable(xprt$summary[[1]])`, but Rmardown throws this error  `! Package array Error: Empty preamble: `l' used.``. I loaded `emmeans`, `knitr`, `kableExtra` and `tinytex`. I have `tinytex` as a suggestion from the error. `Error: LaTeX failed to compile testpdf.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See testpdf.log for more info.
Execution halted`

Comment: Hmmm. Well i did get it to work with HTML as you can see in the recently-updated "basics" vignette.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I am happy with the `xtable` suggestion for now. Maybe as other involved packages updates, things will fall into their places.